# How to reduce gap between two \begin{eqnarray} .... \end{eqnarray}?

Tags: equations, eqnarray

I have two equations of `\begin{eqnarray} .... \end{eqnarray}` in latex using editor WinEdt. How can I reduce the space between them?

```
\begin{eqnarray}

l(P_5) = abc

\end{eqnarray}

\begin{eqnarray}

l(P_6) = xyz

\end{eqnarray}
```

This gives a gap between two equations. Is it possible to reduce the gap to make the article better? Kindly help.

Comment: Never use `eqnarray` to begin with.

Comment: @egreg I need equation numbers for further referencing in the article. That's why I used this. Kindly suggest some other alternatives. Thanks :)

Comment: Use the `amsmath` (everyone else does) and its `align`, `gather`, etc envs. For one lines always use `equation`. Note that `eqnarray` is only available for backwards compatability, new users should never use it, it has many flaws.

Comment: I suggest that you also take a look at this to broaden your horizon: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/197/167081

Comment: The spacing also totally changes when you add you equations in separate paragraphs (separate them using blank lines).

Comment: @JohnKormylo -- I assume you mean to separate the *paragraphs* by blank lines, not the equations.  An equation (or group of equations) should *never* be preceded by a blank line, because it causes the defined pre-display spacing to be ignored (among other adverse effects); a blank line following a display indicates the start of a new paragraph, which is okay.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since it looks like you are *not* using the alignment facilities of the `eqnarray` environment, and since there are [much better alternatives](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/196/5001) to `eqnarray`, I would like to suggest that you load the `amsmath` package and employ its `gather` environment:

```
\begin{gather}
l(P_5) = abc \label{eq:P5} \\
l(P_6) = xyz \label{eq:P6}
\end{gather}
```

Note that one can even save on the pure typing effort by writing `gather` (6 letters, twice) instead of `eqnarray` (8 letters, four times). Observe that it's very easy to cross-reference either of the equations.

Comment: Thank you, thank you, thank you so much, It is so easy and convenient to use.